# Переименовать все файлы в папке - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно, что бы я мог выбрать папку(использую интерфейс на tkinter) и программа сколько бы там не было файлов переименовывала все файлы. Это можно и реализовать и проще, что бы человек вписывал расширение и программа добавляла допустим как каждому файлу

```
while есть еще файлы
    n +=1
    ......('n' + '.' + 'касширение')
    перейти к следующему файлу
```

просмотрел достаточно много документации, но так и не нашел, как это можно сделать. Мне нужен именно этот кусочек кода, отвечающий за пока есть файл: переименовывать его, перейти к следующему, переименовать его. Допустим в папке 200 фото формата png(который задал пользователь) с названием из каши символов и в конце работы программы они превратятся в 200 файлов с названием от 1.png до 200.png, или наоборот пользователю нужна каша(с этим я разберусь, если пойму хотя бы, как сделать то, что я спрашивал)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полностью рабочий код.

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

def selectDir():
    return fd.askdirectory()+'/'

def startRename(directory):
    directory1=directory.replace('/', '\\')
    ext = ent1.get()
    files=sorted([path for path in os.listdir(directory) if os.path.isfile(directory+path) and path.endswith(ext)])
    i=0

    while files:
        file=files[0]
        if not os.path.isfile(f'{directory}{i}.{ext}'):
            name = f'{i}.{ext}'
            os.rename(directory1+file, directory1+name)
            del files[0]
        i+=1


root = Tk()
root.geometry('350x75')

l1=Label(text='Расширение файла (без точки)')
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

ent1 = Entry()
ent1.grid(row=1, column=0)

b1 = Button(text='Выбрать папку', command=lambda: startRename(selectDir()))
b1.grid(row=0,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Вариант №2 (без выбора расширения):

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

def selectDir():
    return fd.askdirectory()+'/'

def startRename(directory):
    directory1=directory.replace('/', '\\')
    files=sorted([path for path in os.listdir(directory) if os.path.isfile(directory+path)])
    i=0

    while files:
        file=files[0]
        ext=file.split('.')[-1]
        if not os.path.isfile(f'{directory}{i}.{ext}'):
            name = f'{i}.{ext}'
            os.rename(directory1+file, directory1+name)
            del files[0]
        i+=1


root = Tk()
root.geometry('350x75')

b1 = Button(text='Выбрать папку', command=lambda: startRename(selectDir()))
b1.grid(row=0,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Зачем так странно. Есть же os.rename().

Comment: @Эникейщик забыл про нее

Comment: Программа же ничего не делает. Зарпашивает расширения, а затем завершается

Comment: @DIPPEROK Программа работает с верными данными. Вы указали тот путь, в котором у вас лежат файлы ?

Comment: @n1tr0xs directory = r'C:\Users\Vazge\Desktop\ok' - скорее всего я просто что-то неправильно сделал(я совсем новичок)

Comment: @DIPPEROK в `directory` должен быть путь с прямым слешем /, а у вас с обратным.

Comment: @n1tr0xs , извините, я не совсем понимаю. Я копирую пусть к папке. Что мне надо сделать с этим? C:\Users\Vazge\Desktop\ok

Comment: @DIPPEROK заменить все символы `\` на `/`.

Comment: @n1tr0xs directory = r'C:/Users/Vazge/Desktop/ok'  я уверен что проблема только во мне конечно.... но ничего не работает, извиняюсь за глупость и непонимание.

Comment: @DIPPEROK в конце пути тоже нужен `/`. Подождите немного, я обновлю код на полностью рабочий с `tkinter`

Comment: изменил код на полностью рабочий и автономный

Comment: @n1tr0xs Можно ли поменять этот код, что бы программа меня только название(без расширений)?

Comment: @DIPPEROK она и так расширение не меняет. Она просто спрашивает какое расширение переименовывать. Или вы хотите чтобы расширение не нужно было указывать ?

Comment: @n1tr0xs в том то и дело, что я применил к папке, не указав расширение и она просто сломала все файлы оставив их без расширения. Да, я хотел бы убрать вообще возможность его вписывать.(Я думал если что то поправить или поменять - справлюсь сам, но видимо 1.5 книжек по питону и пара десятков гайдов недостаточно). Вообще по идеи мне бы сделать так, что бы при выборе папки - путь вписывался в другой энтри и там уже была кнопка профильтровать(с этим надеюсь я сам как нибудь справлюсь), но вот то, что программа ломает безвозвратно файлы - это неприятно. Мне бы убрать возможность менять расширение.

Comment: дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

В python3 есть стандартный кроссплатформенный модуль для работы с файлами.
Ниже представлен пример создания тестового набора файлов и дальнейшего переименовывания файлов по запрашиваемому расширению.

```
import uuid
from pathlib import Path


def create_test_files(parent_dir: Path):
    for i in range(0, 200):
        new_file = '%s.png' % str(uuid.uuid4())
        parent_dir.joinpath(new_file).open('a').close()

    for i in range(0, 200):
        new_file = '%s.txt' % str(uuid.uuid4())
        parent_dir.joinpath(new_file).open('a').close()


def enumerate_files(dir_path: Path, ext: str):
    # формируем маску для поиска
    path_mask = '*.%s' % ext
    # исключаем директории
    only_files = [
        f for f in dir_path.glob(path_mask)
        if f.is_file()
    ]
    # указываем `start`, если необходимо начинать индексацию не с 0
    for idx, f_path in enumerate(only_files, start=1):
        # формируем новый полный путь,  
        # иначе файлы будут созданы в директории, где была запущена программа
        new_path = dir_path.joinpath('%d.%s' % (idx, ext))
        f_path.rename(new_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent_dir = Path('.\\dir\\')
    create_test_files(parent_dir)

    enumerate_files(parent_dir, 'png')
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот это чудеса тут понаписали

```
import os
ext = 'your_ext'
for file in os.listdir('your_path'):
    os.rename(file, f'{file}.{ext}')
```

Переименует все файлы в директории добавив к ним расширение ext, ну или как там вам надо это сделать

```
import os
ext = "your_ext"
new_ext = "new_ext"
for file in os.listdir('your_dir'):
    if file.endswith(ext):
            os.rename(file, f'{os.path.splitext(file)[0]}.{new_ext}')
```

Это для переименования формата

Решение вопроса на самом деле

```
import os

ext = "your_ext"
i = 1
dir = 'your_dir'
for file in os.listdir(dir):
    if file.endswith(ext):
        os.rename(f'{dir}/{file}', f'{dir}/{i}.{ext}')
        i = i + 1
```

Comment: В модуле `os` есть метод `path.splitext`, который разделяет на путь и расширение файла.

Comment: ваш код не является ответом на вопрос. Прочитайте вопрос еще раз.

Comment: @n1tr0xs, мне кажется является. По крайней мере, на мой взгляд, подходит под описание в вопросе. Там ведь нет примеров, так что понимаем как хотим :). Чем же все-таки не является?

Comment: @Mattern ваш код переименовывает из одного расширения в другое. А нужно, чтобы файлы переименовывались в такую штуку: `1.png` `2.png` `3.png` .... `100.png`  и так далее, только если это файлы были расширения `png`. Расширение `png` соответственно можно заменить на любое другое.

Comment: @n1tr0xs, o, то есть файлы имеют любое имя, и все они переименовываются в порядок с расширением. Вы правы, сейчас поправлю

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще более рабочий код

```
import os
def startRename():
    directory = f"{os.getcwd()}\\"
    directory1=directory.replace('/', '\\')
    files=os.listdir(directory)
    for file in files:
        os.rename(directory1+file, directory1+file.replace('.Без названия',''))
startRename()
```